# Invalid URL or Resource Not found when using ImageView

Tags: javafx-8

I have a problem when i tried to use ImageView function.

I tried a lot of tutorial and still doesn't work. For example:

```
Image img= new Image(new ImageView("D:picture\\img1.jpg"));
pane.getChildren().add(img);
```

I've also tried to use [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kR-jnEVzzrA) tutorial but still failed.

the only method that works for me is:

```
javafx.scene.image.Image img = new javafx.scene.image.Image(getClass().getResource("logo1.jpg").toExternalForm());
    ImageView img1 = new ImageView(img);
```

which is quite lengthy. 
Are there any way to fix this?

Comment: It depends on whether you want to access a file (as in the first case) or a resource. In the former case refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609896/cannot-construct-an-image-object-with-relative-file-path-without-using-file-pre/39611326#39611326 In both cases you can create a helper method that allows you to reduce the code duplication if you need to do this in multiple places. BTW: Passing an `ImageView` to the `Image` constructor won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
Image loginImage = new Image("file:login.png");
ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
imageView.setImage(loginImage);
```

Comment: Also, `ImageView` constructor internally creates an new instance of `Image` with the given `String`. So no need to create a variable for `loginImage`.